# Merging several columns in one new column in the same pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, merge, dataframe

So i have 5 columns in a dataframe that i like merge as a list in an existing column. A subset of the dataframe is below:

```
           loclize_indices_region   i1    i2      i3       i4            i5
survey ID                                                                   
59988455                       NaN  CIS   NaN     NaN      NaN           NaN
59988455                       NaN  CIS   NaN     NaN      NaN  Main Indices
59988455                       NaN  CIS   NaN     NaN      NaN           NaN
59988455                       NaN  NaN   NaN  Europe  America  Main Indices
59988455                       NaN  NaN   NaN     NaN      NaN           NaN
59988455                       NaN  CIS  APAC  Europe      NaN           NaN
59988455                       NaN  CIS   NaN     NaN      NaN           NaN
59988455                       NaN  CIS   NaN     NaN      NaN  Main Indices
59988455                       NaN  NaN   NaN     NaN      NaN           NaN
59988455                       NaN  NaN  APAC     NaN      NaN  Main Indices
59988455                       NaN  CIS   NaN  Europe  America           NaN
59988455                       NaN  NaN   NaN     NaN      NaN  Main Indices
59988455                       NaN  CIS   NaN     NaN      NaN           NaN
```

What i'm after is to fill    `'loclize_indices_region'`    column by merging columns (i1, i2, i3, i4, i5) and create a list without the `NaN`. Below how the end result should look like:

```
survey ID                    loclize_indices_region 
59988455                                      [CIS]
59988455                        [CIS, Main Indices]
59988455                                      [CIS]
59988455            [Europe, America, Main Indices]
59988455                                         []
59988455                        [CIS, APAC, Europe]
59988455                                      [CIS]
59988455                        [CIS, Main Indices]
59988455                                         []
59988455                       [APAC, Main Indices]
59988455                     [CIS, Europe, America]
59988455                             [Main Indices]
```

the code below perfectly fine, but i need to create a function that will do that for me rather than creating lambda functions for every block of columns that i like to merge. (I still have other similar columns that i like to apply the same logic on them.)

```
data['loclize_indices_region'] = data.apply(lambda x: [x['i1'], x['i2'], x['i3'], x['i4'], x['i5']], axis=1)
data['loclize_indices_region'] = data.loclize_indices_region.map(lambda x: [i for i in x if str(i) != 'nan'], 1)
```

i tried to write the below function that intended to use in `data.apply()`, but for some reason it doesn't work:

```
def merge_cols(series, *cols):
    list = [series[i] for i in cols]
    list = [ l for l in list if l !='nan']
    return list

list [i1, i2, i3, i4, i5]

data['loclize_indices_region'] = data.apply(merge_cols(*list), 1)
```

i'm getting the below error instead

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/u8003461/SkyDrive/Python/Eikon Russian Survey/data_discovery.py", line 26, in <module>
    list [i1, i2, i3, i4, i5]
NameError: name 'i1' is not defined
```

any idea how to do this operation error free?

Thanks,
Mo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `df` is your DataFrame with `survey ID` being an index you could do this in one line:

```
df['loclize_indices_region'] = df.loc[:,df.columns.tolist()[1:]].apply(lambda x: x.dropna().tolist(), 1)
```

or provide a list of columns separately:

```
cols = ['i1', ... ,'i5']
df['loclize_indices_region'] = df.loc[:,cols].apply(lambda x: x.dropna().tolist(), 1)
```

Note that column names are strings so `i1` should be `'i1'` in your list of columns.

OR, if you must to use external function:

```
def merge_cols(x, cols):
    return x.loc(axis=1)[cols].dropna().tolist()

cols = df.columns.tolist()[1:]

df['loclize_indices_region'] = df.apply(merge_cols, cols=cols, axis=1)
```

Comment: thanks @Primer for your help, it works beautifully. Would you mind shed some light on the use of `df.loc`? what exactly its role in the above code?

Comment: It is recommended that `.loc` attribute is used as the primary label based access method to avoid problems with chained assignment. So there is no harm in using it even if the need might not be so obvious as in the above dummy example (it's a matter of habit I guess). You will able to find more information about it in the [official docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-label), including examples when not using `.loc` will give you a problem.