# Error in merging pandas data frame columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to merge three columns from the same data frame into one.

Here my data frame `selected_vals`

```
   label_1                         label_2                   label_3   
0  NaN                              NaN                      NaN
1  ('__label__Religione_e_Magia',)  NaN                      NaN
2  NaN                            ('__label__Storia',)       NaN
3  NaN                            ('__label__Storia',)       NaN
4 ('__label__Religione_e_Magia',)  NaN                       NaN
```

The dataframe has only one value per row so, in the col where the value it's not specified I'm having `NaN`
Following the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27291870/merging-several-columns-in-one-new-column-in-the-same-pandas-dataframe) I used this code:

```
selected_vals['selected_vals'] =  selected_vals.loc[:,selected_vals.columns.tolist()[1:]].apply(lambda x: x.dropna().tolist(), 1)
```

However, by doing so, only the values from the col `label_2` are in the col `selected_vals`

Here the ouput

```
 label_1                         label_2                   label_3  selected_vals   
0  NaN                              NaN                      NaN      []
1  ('__label__Religione_e_Magia',)  NaN                      NaN      []
2  NaN                            ('__label__Storia',)       NaN      ('__label__Storia',)
3  NaN                            ('__label__Storia',)       NaN      ('__label__Storia',)
4 ('__label__Religione_e_Magia',)  NaN
```

As desired output I would like to have all the values stored in the same col i.e

```
   selected_vals                              
0  NaN                              
1  ('__label__Religione_e_Magia',)  
2  ('__label__Storia',)                                   
3  ('__label__Storia',)                            
4 ('__label__Religione_e_Magia',)
```

Suggestions about how to deal with this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select all columns without first, then forward fiiling missing values and last select last column:

```
#replace NaN strings to np.nan if necessary
selected_vals = selected_vals.replace('NaN', np.nan)

selected_vals['selected_vals'] =  selected_vals.iloc[:,1:].ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately I'm still having the same output

Comment: @Pelide - If test `print (selected_vals.iloc[:,1:],isna())` get `True`s for `NaN`s?

Comment: @Pelide - If not, try `selected_vals = selected_vals.replace('NaN', np.nan)`

Answer (score 0):

You can apply function to each row and keep only desired value (where column is not NaN)

```py
selected_vals['selected_vals'] = selected_vals.apply(lambda row: row[row[pd.notnull(row)].index.item()], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions.

I think the problem was related to the type of the dataframe.

I solved the issue as follows:

```
selected_vals = selected_vals.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
selected_vals = selected_vals.applymap(str)
df['suggested_label'] = selected_vals["label_1"].astype(str) + selected_vals["label_2"]+ selected_vals["label_3"]

print(df)
```

Don't know if it's correct or not but at least it works for me.